# Add an interface to possible null value with Typescript

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express

I'm using Express, Typescript and the MongoDB Node.JS driver to development my API; at the moment I got a problem with the findOne method because return a promise but, just with an object with the first document was match with query or a simple null if something goes wrong.

So I'm trying to get that object in a variable when the Promise get resolved, so I have something like this:

```
let user = await db.collection('collectionName').findOne({ email: "example@stack.com" });
```

So when I try to set an interface to my variable I recive the next error:

```
let user: UserStructure = await db.collection('collectionName').findOne({ email: "example@stack.com" }); 

// Type 'object | null' is not assignable to type 'UserStructure'.
// Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'UserStructure'.
```

Some advice?

Comment: `let user: UserStructure | null = ...`?

Answer (score 3):

@shanon is correct. TypeScript care about value that is possibly null/undefined which further can cause null reference error.

Optionally you can set `"strictNullChecks":false` in your `tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions`

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try that, because I keep getting the _Object is possibly 'null'_ error.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is typescript is trying its best to protect you, mongodb has marked that function as possibly returning null, yet your code doesn't protect against null.

Change the code to protect against null in a way typescript can analyze and change the type of the variable to allow for null and the error will go away.

```
let user: UserStructure | null = await db.collection('collectionName').findOne({ email: "example@stack.com" });
if(!user) return res.status(400).send("No user could be found")
// user will now be UserStructure after this early return. and not UserStrcuture | null
```

Comment: It partially works, but now when I try to acces one of the properties of the object (e.g. user._id) I get the next error: Object is possibly 'null'.

Comment: With the "if" check that error will go  away, because typescript can understand that you've protected against null. (by returning if user is null).
This will narrrow the type, and strip null away in all code after the if check.